# Scala iterate over two consecutive elements of a list

Tags: list, scala, iteration, pairwise

How would we iterate over two consecutive elements of a list and apply the difference function
For instance I have this :

```
val list = List(List("Eat", "Drink", "Sleep", "work"), List("Eat", "Sleep", "Dance"))
```

I want to iterate over these two consecutive elements and calculate the difference

I've tried this but  I do not know how to iterate over each two consecutive elements

```
list.map((a,b) => a.diff(b))
```

the output should be `List("Drink", "work")`

Comment: What output are you trying to get for these inputs?

Comment: i've edited the question with the desired output

Comment: And what if the input contains more than two lists, what do you want to happen then? Or is the input list always of length two?

Comment: Also that doesn't look like "union" to me? Where does "the union function" enter into this?

Comment: if the list contains more than one, it should iterate over all the possible pairs. the 2 elements were just for illustration

Comment: Ive corrected the post it should be difference instead of union

Comment: What about using **Sets** instead?

Comment: Why Sets instead of Lists ?

Comment: @MunaAr because operations like `diff` are more efficient on **Sets** than on **Lists**. Finally, what exactly do you want to do? You want the difference of all inner sets with all other inner sets?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly you probably want to iterate over a sliding window.

```
list.sliding(2).map{
  case List(a, b) => a.diff(b)
  case List(a) => a
}.toList
```

Alternatively you might also want `grouped(2)` which partitions the list into groups instead.

Comment: does the sliding window parse over  all the possible combinaisons of each element of the list ? or does it just calculates the difference for each two consecutive elements

Comment: @MunaAr why don't you simply check the [**scaladoc**](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html)? Instead of asking?

Comment: Each two consecutive elements.

Answer (score 1):

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val list = List(List("Eat", "Drink", "Sleep", "work"), List("Eat", "Sleep", "Dance"));
    val diff = list.head.diff(list(1))
    println(diff)
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case, match can work perfectly fine:

```
val list = List(List("Eat", "Drink", "Sleep", "work"), List("Eat", "Sleep", "Dance"))
list match { case a :: b :: Nil => a diff b}
```

If the list does not always have 2 items, you should also have a catch-all case in match

Comment: this gives some warning but I did get what you wanted to do Thank you